# Multiple query parameters in Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

What am I doing wrong?

Repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE substring(data,1,10) IN (:data0,:data1)", nativeQuery = true)
List<AgendaModel> find(String data0,String data1);
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/agenda/clone/{data0}/{data1}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<AgendaModel> clone(@PathVariable String data0, String data1){
    return actions.find(data0,data1);
}
```

It works, but send me back just the first data result.
For example if I try to use "/agenda/clone/2022-11-24/2022-11-25" I get the values from 2022-11-24 and no values from 2022-11-25.

Comment: What is executed in the database, and how are you sure you should get results for that second parameter? Turn on SQL logging, and maybe show what the query returns if you run it yourself in the database.

Comment: Into MySQL is running fine, what I was missing is the @PathVariable. Thank you

Comment: You've got the answer, but for next time, the SQL (with parameter logging) would show you it was inputting null instead of your path value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see @PathVariable annotation is missing for data1. Please write method like this and try again.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/agenda/clone/{data0}/{data1}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<AgendaModel> clone(@PathVariable String data0, @PathVariable String data1){
    return actions.find(data0,data1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn´t saw that!